# asp.net GridView how do i pass the hyperlink value to a different page textbox?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

My GridView outputs data from a query and a column is a HyperLinkField. What im trying to do is when you click on a hyperlink value it takes you to the same page and that value is passed onto a textbox.

How do i pass a selected hyperlink value to another page textbox?

**Here is my textbox and HyperLinkValue code**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="GitCertIDTextbox" runat="server" Width="202px"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="Gft_Cert_ID" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="\AccountingReports\Gift_Certificate.aspx" target="_blank" DataTextField="Gft_Cert_ID" HeaderText="Certificate Test"   />
```

Comment: You would have to make the value you want to pass part of the URL (generally via query string). On the receiving page, check the URL to see if that query string value is present. If so, extract the value from the query string and put it in the textbox.

Comment: Well, since the page name is going to be the same as the link, then you can use this: Request.Url.ToString() and not have to pass anything. Since the user is hitting a link, then you not running any code behind on the current page anyway.